# Switch spaces with apple script

Tags: macos, applescript, spaces

My goal is to switch spaces from within an apple script. My shortcut to switch to the 4th space is `ctrl+4`, but when I tried this in an apple script nothing happens:

```
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "4" using {control down}
end tell
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know why, but using key code instead works

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application "System Events" to key code 21 using control down
end tell
```

Comment: If this works for you, you can mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark. This shows the community that the problem has been solved.

Comment: Possibly the reason this works is that the key code for 4 'above qwerty' is 21 but the 4 on the 10-key is 86 & the key commands for switching Spaces are sensitive to that.

Comment: @Arc676 I will, in 2 days when the system will allow it.

Comment: @Tetsujin That makes sense, thanks for your explanation!

Comment: Additional key codes can be found here: https://eastmanreference.com/complete-list-of-applescript-key-codes

Comment: @StevieD Thanks for the link! That is a very nice overview!